# Vagrant runs inline scripts multiple times, and ones which haven't been defined

Tags: scripts, virtualbox, vagrant

I am spinning up multiple vms using vagrant, this is my vagrantfile (up to the first host, removing comments):

```
# Installed Vagrant Version: 2.2.14
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-20.04"
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox

  mount_new_disk = <<-SCRIPT
  sudo useradd -m -s /bin/bash -G sudo testuser1
  sudo echo -e "123\n123"|sudo passwd testuser1
  sudo mkdir /mnt/da
  sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb
  sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/da
  echo "/dev/sdb /mnt/da ext4 auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0" |sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
  SCRIPT

  make_default_gw = <<-SCRIPT
  superda=$(sudo ip route show|head -1|awk '{print $3}');if ! [[ $superda =~ "192.168.1.254" ]]; then echo "router is not default, removing";sudo ip route del default via $superda ;else echo "yes it's default, gud";fi
  SCRIPT

  nfs_host = <<-SCRIPT
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install nfs-kernel-server
  echo "/mnt/da    10.118.8.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)"|sudo tee -a /etc/exports
  sudo chown nobody:nogroup /mnt/da
  sudo chmod 777 /mnt/da
  sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server
  sudo ufw allow from 10.118.8.0/24 to any port nfs
  sudo ufw allow from 10.118.8.0/24 to any port ssh
  sudo ufw enable
  SCRIPT

  nfs_client = <<-SCRIPT
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install nfs-common
  sudo mkdir /mnt/nfs
  sudo mount 10.118.8.10:/mnt/da /mnt/nfs
  echo "10.118.8.10:/mnt/da    /mnt/nfs   nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0" |sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
  SCRIPT

  config.vm.define "da1" do |da1|
    da1.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
    da1.vm.disk :disk, name: "backup", size: "10GB"
      da1.vm.hostname = "da1"
      da1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.118.8.10"
    da1.vm.network "public_network", use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true, netmask: "255.255.255.0", bridge: "Intel(R) I211 Gigabit Network Connection"
    da1.vm.provision :shell, :inline => mount_new_disk
    da1.vm.provision :shell, :inline => make_default_gw
    da1.vm.provision :shell, :inline => nfs_host
      config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  end

  config.vm.define "da2" do |da2|
    da2.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
    da2.vm.disk :disk, name: "backup", size: "10GB"
      da2.vm.hostname = "da2"
      da2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.118.8.11"
    da2.vm.network "public_network", use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true, netmask: "255.255.255.0", bridge: "Intel(R) I211 Gigabit Network Connection"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => mount_new_disk
    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => make_default_gw
    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => nfs_client
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  end

  config.vm.define "da3" do |da3|
    da3.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
    da3.vm.disk :disk, name: "backup", size: "10GB"
    da3.vm.hostname = "da3"
    da3.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.118.8.12"
      da3.vm.network "public_network", use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true, netmask: "255.255.255.0", bridge: "Intel(R) I211 Gigabit Network Connection"
#    da3.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 5555
    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => mount_new_disk
    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => make_default_gw
    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => nfs_client
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  end
```

Now the scripts `mount_new_disk` and `make_default_gw` should run on all hosts, while `nfs_host` should only run on `da1`, and `nfs_client` should only run on `da[23]`.

But for some readon, every script runs on every host, and they also run multiple times.

Note that the tutorial I followed said to write `config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => mount_new_disk`, but I also tried with `da1.vm.provision :shell, :inline => mount_new_disk` with the same result.

For example: I will write an `echo 'RUNNING SCRIPT START: ...'` at the top and `echo 'RUNNING SCRIPT END: ...'` at the bottom of each script to see which, and how many times it ran (captured the output then grepped it):

```
unu@here:~/yes$ grep -n 'RUNNING SCRIPT' opt
44:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT START: mount_new_disk
62:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT STOP: mount_new_disk
65:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT START: make_default_gw
67:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT STOP: make_default_gw
70:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT START: nfs_client
120:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT STOP: nfs_client
123:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT START: mount_new_disk
137:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT STOP: mount_new_disk
140:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT START: make_default_gw
142:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT STOP: make_default_gw
145:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT START: nfs_client
174:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT STOP: nfs_client
177:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT START: mount_new_disk
191:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT STOP: mount_new_disk
194:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT START: make_default_gw
196:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT STOP: make_default_gw
199:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT START: nfs_host
261:    da1: RUNNING SCRIPT STOP: nfs_host
```

As you can see it ran all the scripts (even those that weren't mentioned in their own config section), and it ran them multiple times.

Funnily enough, on da2, which is a nfs client, it didn't run the `nfs_host` script, but it still ran everything else twice:

```
unu@here:~/yes$ grep -n 'RUNNING SCRIPT' noua
41:    da2: RUNNING SCRIPT START: mount_new_disk
61:    da2: RUNNING SCRIPT STOP: mount_new_disk
64:    da2: RUNNING SCRIPT START: make_default_gw
66:    da2: RUNNING SCRIPT STOP: make_default_gw
69:    da2: RUNNING SCRIPT START: nfs_client
118:    da2: RUNNING SCRIPT STOP: nfs_client
121:    da2: RUNNING SCRIPT START: mount_new_disk
134:    da2: RUNNING SCRIPT STOP: mount_new_disk
137:    da2: RUNNING SCRIPT START: make_default_gw
139:    da2: RUNNING SCRIPT STOP: make_default_gw
142:    da2: RUNNING SCRIPT START: nfs_client
171:    da2: RUNNING SCRIPT STOP: nfs_client
```

Now I know I could just put all of this in the configuration section itself, like so:

```
  config.vm.define "da1" do |da1|
    da1.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
    da1.vm.disk :disk, name: "backup", size: "10GB"
      da1.vm.hostname = "da1"
      da1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.118.8.10"
    da1.vm.network "public_network", use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true, netmask: "255.255.255.0", bridge: "Intel(R) I211 Gigabit Network Connection"
    da1.vm.provision :shell, :inline => mount_new_disk
    da1.vm.provision :shell, :inline => make_default_gw
    da1.vm.provision :shell, :inline => nfs_host
    da1.vm.provision :shell, :inline => <<-SCRIPT
    echo "yohoho and a bottle of rum!"
    SCRIPT
      config.ssh.forward_agent = true
```

But the other way, to just call it when needed, is much more convenient.

Does anybody know why this happens? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: I have to replace `config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => script_name` with the appropriate vm name, depending on the config block.

So for `da1` I did `da1.vm.provision :shell, :inline => script_name`, for `da2` I did `da2.vm.provision :shell, :inline => script_name` and for `da3` I did `da3.vm.provision :shell, :inline => script_name`.